# What is the best Chess Engine to practice latter Middlegame and Early Endgame

Tags: engines, analysis, endgame, strategy, software

I have taken a break from chess for while now, and I am hoping to make a comeback soon. I want to brush up on my latter Middlegame and Early Endgame.

I want to start by analyzing recent GM games. What is the best engine as of now for this task?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Computer Chess Rating List (CCRL) rankings](https://ccrl.chessdom.com/ccrl/) | [Chess Engine Grand Tournament (CEGT) rankings](http://www.cegt.net/)  (_acknowledge this doesn't address utility for OP's stated purposes_)

Comment: I cannot imagine how to choose between engines with this criteria.  Curious to see the answers and reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

Improving our middlegame and endgame is a task that lasts our entire life. For that reason, please do not expect quick results whatever you do. Chess is one of the most difficult challenges for the human mind. We need to improve step by step, day by day. For training it is better to study books written for experts. Which one? Depends on your level. For example, to improve our endgame, ***Chess Fundamentals, by José Raúl Capablanca*** would be excellent for players that are at the beginning of their career, but ***Mark Dvoretsky's Endgame Manual*** would be appropriate for more advanced players. ***After you have studied the endgame, you can practice it with the latest version of Stockfish that is available on lichess.org for free*** (Level 8 never makes mistakes. Level 1 makes mistakes in all the moves. In the middle of the spectrum, you find levels 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, and 2. Pick the level that you like the most). Same can be done with a strategy book, for example, ***The Giants of Strategy, by Neil McDonald***. Equal formula with a tactics book. My favorite is ***Combinative Motifs, by Maxim Blokh***. ***The website Chessable integrates the e-book and the engine, so you can do both on their website***. When I analyze my games, I use the newest version of Stockfish on lichess.org, but you need to give it enough hardware resources and enough time if you want a good analysis. ***You can always search with Google: lichess+analysis+board.*** But currently, this is the link: https://lichess.org/analysis